# Linear Dependent- Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have two vectors: $(x,y)$ and $(2,0)$. These vectors are linearly dependent. What does this fact tell us about the vectors. Like what equation can we setup. It seems if they were linearly independent then we could say $(x,y)\cdot (2,0) = 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by $*$?

Comment: @TaraB I assumed he meant the usual scalar product.

Comment: @GitGud I don't understand your edit.

Comment: I meant to say * as in dot product so (x,y) dot prod (2,0)

Comment: @TaraB I used $|$ to denote the dot product. It that what was bothering you?

Comment: I've never seen dot product denoted like that before, so I think $*$ was better.  I'd have just used $\cdot$ myself.

Comment: @TaraB I'm used to it. Didn't know it was uncommon. I changed to a more common notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're considering **only two** vectors $(x,y)$ and $(2,0)$, them being linearly dependent means that $(x,y)=\lambda (2,0)$, for some scalar $\lambda$, i.e., $(x,y)=(2\lambda ,0\cdot \lambda)=(2\lambda ,0)$, therefore $(x,y)=(2\lambda, 0)$.

Also note that it is possible for two vectors $u,v$ to be linearly independent without necessarily having $u\cdot v=0$, where $\cdot$ denotes the usual dot product. For instance take $u=(1,1)$ and $v=(1,0)$. We have $u,v$ linearly independent and $u\cdot v=1\neq0$. The converse, however - with the additional condition that both $u,v$ aren't the null vector -is true, that is, if $u\cdot v=0$ and $u\neq0\neq v$, then $u,v$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @AllenMiller Glad I could help.